# Can we pass alexa serial number in alexa intent?

Tags: uid, serial-number, alexa-skills-kit

I want to uniquely identify the alexa intent, from which alexa serial number this specific intent is coming from. I have all the alexa serial number added in my database ,it is also mapped to some other table using foreign key.whenever any alexa intent request comes I want to fetch the data of other entity which is mapped to alexa serial number from where the request has been arrived.

Please help if there is any way to pass alexa serial number in intent request.

Answer (score 0):

### Serial number

What do you mean with:

> I have all the alexa serial number added in my data

- Where did you get the serial number initially from?
- From the device itself? How do you know who is using the skill?
- You do not get the serial numbers from the Alexa Requests.

### Existing Ids in the requests

- Maybe you are talking about the **deviceId** ?
- What do you want to achieve with the serial number? Most probably you want to store user data for later requests - thats where the **userId** will help
- Here are details about the Ids: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#request-body-syntax